# Every 5th row is different when using striped on kable_styling

Tags: r-markdown, kable, kableextra

When I use `kable_styling` with `latex_options = "striped"`, I noticed that every 5th row is different. It appears to be higher than the other rows. The output format is PDF.

````
    ---
    title: "Title"
    author: "myself"
    date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%e. %B %Y')`"
    output: pdf_document
    ---
    ```{r}
    df <- data.frame(list("one", "0.05 to 0.2", "0.02"))
    df <- rbind(df, list("two", "30 to 40", "1"))
    df <- rbind(df, list("three", "0.2 to 0.8", "0.1"))
    df <- rbind(df, list("four", "30 to 35", "1"))
    df <- rbind(df, list("five", "0.2 to 0.8", "0.1"))
    df <- rbind(df, list("six", "occupancy", ""))
    df <- rbind(df, list("seven", "true", ""))
    df <- rbind(df, list("eight", "10", ""))
    df <- rbind(df, list("nine", "", ""))
    df <- rbind(df, list("ten", "abc", ""))
    df <- rbind(df, list("eleven", "false", ""))
    df <- rbind(df, list("twelve", "Monday", ""))
    colnames(df) <- c("Variable", "Values", "Stepsize")
    kbl(df, caption="independent Variables", booktabs=T, align = c("l", "c", "c")) %>%
      kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "HOLD_position"))
    ```
````

Notice the two rows, six and ten:

[image]

Comment: That is not the result of the `striped` option. Using `booktabs = T` adds `\\addlinespace` after every 5th row to make big tables more readable. You can remove that by using `linesep = NA`.

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer ok, i did not notice that, thank you!